# Как отправить 4 сообщения Telegram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Хочу,чтобы отправилось 4 сообщения с текстом (1,2,3,4)

Пример: http://prntscr.com/no243v

Но при запуске скрипта просто выводятся цифры

Пример: http://prntscr.com/no2iqc

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, InlineQueryHandler, CommandHandler
import requests
import re
def numbs(bot, update):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
for i in range(1,5):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=i)
def main():
    updater = Updater('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('gg',numbs))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ваш код синтаксически некорректен и в принципе не способен запуститься. Подозреваю, вы нас немного обманываете и на самом деле запускаете немного не такой код

Comment: @andreymal да,чуть обманул(запустил не тот скрипт и вставил старый код)

Comment: Тот код, который вы показали теперь, тоже не способен запуститься. Вы нас продолжаете обманывать.

Comment: @andreymal установите python-telegram-bot

Comment: Это ни при чём, у вас в цикле вне функции используется несуществующая переменная `bot` — что бы я ни установил, переменная не появится и код не заработает.

Comment: @andreymal у меня работает https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKPrVg_2sWI

Comment: Ну где ж работает, если он прямо на вашем видео ошибку выдал

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93598/discussion-between-denis-frolov-and-andreymal).